# How to pair a BLE device in linux without using gatttool?

Tags: bluetooth

Some bluetooth low-energy (BLE) devices are difficult to pair in linux. All information I can find (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412242/zmk-nice60-does-not-pair-with-ubuntu) question) suggests that `gatttool` should be used, like so:

```
sudo gatttool -t random -b E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB -I
[E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB][LE]> connect
```

Unfortunately `gatttool` is deprecated and no longer distributed in several linux distributions.

The [archlinux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth#Deprecated_BlueZ_tools) says that `btgatt-client` is supposed to replace `gatttool`. I have tried the following, without success:

```
$ btgatt-client -d F9:B9:1D:A5:73:F4 -t random -v
btgatt-client: Opening L2CAP LE connection on ATT channel:
     src: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    dest: F9:B9:1D:A5:73:F4
Connecting to device... Done
[GATT client]# att: (chan 0x5623a9b9d6e0) ATT op 0x08
[GATT client]# att: < 08 01 00 ff ff 3a 2b                             .....:+         
[GATT client]# att: Channel 0x5623a9b9d6e0 disconnected: Software caused connection abort
[GATT client]# gatt: Primary service discovery failed. ATT ECODE: 0x00
[GATT client]# gatt: Failed to initialize gatt-client
[GATT client]# GATT discovery procedures failed - error code: 0x00
[GATT client]# Device disconnected: Software caused connection abort
```

Unfortunately due to lack of documentation I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your original question, `bluetoothctl` should be used for pairing. You can also use `btmgmt` beforehand to set up your device properly. These are the steps that I usually follow in order to pair devices on Linux:

1. Configure your device to be discoverable, connectable, and pairable

   ```
   sudo btmgmt power off
   sudo btmgmt discov on
   sudo btmgmt connectable on
   sudo btmgmt pairable on
   sudo btmgmt power on
   ```
2. Set up your device to accept numerical pairing

   ```
   bluetoothctl --agent KeyboardDisplay
   ```
3. Then, if your device is the peripheral, you should just wait until a pairing request is made from the remote device.

If your device is the central, then you can initiate pairing using the following command:

```
pair 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

Where `00:11:22:33:44:55` is the address of the device you want to pair to (you can find the address using the `scan on`/`scan off` commands).

Below are a few links that have more information which may help you answer your question:

- [Raspberry BLE encryption/pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147384/raspberry-ble-encryption-pairing)
- [BLE pairing the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/12/19/tutorial-ble-pairing-the-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-with-hexiwear/)
- [Configuring Bluetooth devices with bluetoothctl](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/197/Command-Line-bluetoothctl)
- [How to Encrypt Data Using BLE Connection Using BlueZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369175/how-to-encrypt-data-using-ble-connection-using-bluez5-50/54378858#54378858)