# Fail to connect Bluetooth LE keyboard with bluetoothctl

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, bluez

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Tablet gen 2.  I recently bought a Lenovo Trackpoint Keyboard II which uses Bluetooth LE.  Using a [Stack Exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678573/how-to-pair-a-ble-device-in-linux-without-using-gatttool), I was able to get the Bluetooth LE keyboard working once with

```
sudo -i 
btmgmt power off
btmgmt discov on
btmgmt connectable on
btmgmt pairable on
btmgmt power on
bluetoothctl --agent KeyboardDisplay
```

and then

```
connect 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

But after it working once I am getting the error

```
Attempting to connect to 00:11:22:33:44:55
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed le-connection-abort-by-local
```

The output of `info 00:11:22:33:44:55`  is

```
Device 00:11:22:33:44:55 (random)
    Name: TrackPoint Keyboard II
    Alias: TrackPoint Keyboard II
    Appearance: 0x03c1
    Icon: input-keyboard
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    WakeAllowed: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v17EFp60E1d0047
```

`systemctl status bluetooth` gives

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-09-19 15:38:20 EDT; 21h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 108246 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9096)
     Memory: 2.2M
        CPU: 1min 11.582s
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─108246 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 19 15:38:20 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.3360 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_>
Sep 19 15:38:20 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.3360 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Sep 19 15:38:20 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.3360 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_>
Sep 19 18:59:26 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_7B_23_56_84_6A/fd0: fd(33) ready
Sep 19 20:20:03 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free V>
Sep 20 04:06:53 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_7B_23_56_84_6A/sep1/fd1: fd(33) ready
Sep 20 11:21:06 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_7B_23_56_84_6A/sep1/fd2: fd(33) ready
Sep 20 11:48:31 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_parse_rej() SET_CONFIGURATION request rejecte>
Sep 20 11:48:31 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free V>
Sep 20 11:48:32 hamm bluetoothd[108246]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for C>
```

What can I do to diagnose and correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some more searching on the internet and found this [arch linux post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263172)  which suggested `sudo bluetoothctl remove 00:11:22:33:44:55` and then pairing and connecting via the standard system bluetooth controls (gui).  I did this and now the keyboard has worked for two different sessions.