# Bluetoth LE and Linux

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I recently bought a Bluetooth LE keyboard and was able to [connect to it only once with my Ubuntu 22.04 Thinkpad X1 Tablet, with failed connections every other time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757079/fail-to-connect-bluetooth-le-keyboard-with-bluetoothctl).  As far as I can tell command line is the only way to work with Bluetoth LE in Linux.

1. What about Bluetooth LE makes it more tricky to use?
2. Why is there not a GUI control of Bluetooth LE in Linux?